# Remove digits from string in Sybase SQL Anywhere 16

Tags: sql, regex, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am looking for the best method to remove digit characters from ASCII text within Sybase SQL Anywhere 16. Is there any method of doing this which does not resort to nested `REPLACE()` calls, loops etc.?

Example:

`This 1.00 is 200 a test 333 string.` becomes `This is a test string.`

Comment: See my rewritten answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020273/regex-to-match-all-non-digit-characters-which-are-interspersed-with-digits/36020483#36020483). It has an example from Sybase docs using lookarounds that you mentioned, on a nearly identical problem.  Apologies if you saw this already.

Answer (score 0):

As ASE supports regular expressions:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, ' *[[:digit:]]+.?[[:digit:]]+', '')
```

This removes [decimal] numbers with optional leading spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using ASE and do not have access to REGEXP_REPLACE() or any regex enabled replace functions. SQL Anywhere does provide REPLACE(str, find_str, replace_str) and REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, regex). If there was a regex to match all alphanumeric characters but not match decimal characters I think I could make it work.

Comment: @ldueck: Sorry, I don't think there's any way simple way to do what you want without `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the digits are always separated from the alphanumeric words, this should work:

```
SELECT LIST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tst_string,'(^|[[:blank:]])[[:alpha:]]+', 1, n.row_num),'')
FROM sa_rowgenerator(1,length(tst_string)) n;
```